# I have a good (working) indicator, but it is in version Pine2. It is not converted to version Pine3 and writes such errors:

Tags: pine-script

I have a good (working) indicator, but it is in version Pine2. It is not converted to version Pine3 and writes such errors:

//Error  Undeclared identifier bb;
FFF (xx,xxur,wwur)=>      bb=(xx < xxur) ? 1: (xx > wwur) ? 2 : (xx > 50 ) ? 0 :  bb[1]
bb
//Error  Undeclared identifier rrmin;
rrmin=(ttrr==2) ? 100 : (rsrs[0]<rrmin[0] ? rsrs[0] : rrmin[1])

//Error Undeclared identifier ddmin;
ddmin=(ddtt==2) ? 100 : (dmark[0]<ddmin[0] ? dmark[0] : ddmin[1])

//Error Undeclared identifier ssmin;
ssmin=(sstt==2) ? 100 : (kk[0]<ssmin[0] ? kk[0] : ssmin[1])

//Error Undeclared identifier rrmax;
rrmax=(ttrr==1) ? 0 : (rsrs[0]>rrmax[0] ? rsrs[0] : rrmax[1])

//Error Undeclared identifier ddmax;
ddmax=(ddtt==1) ? 0 : (dmark[0]>ddmax[0] ? dmark[0] : ddmax[1])

//Error Undeclared identifier ssmax
ssmax=(sstt==1) ? 0 : (kk[0]>ssmax[0] ? kk[0] : ssmax[1])

Comment: Edit your question and paste the full code. it is hard to help you without the context

Answer (score 0):

First declare the variable, and then [reassign it](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Variable_declarations.html?#variable-reassignment)
Something like this:

```
//@version=3
study(title="test", overlay = false)

rss = rsi(close,14)
rsrs = sma(rss,1)

FFF (xx,xxur,wwur)=>
    bb = 0.0
    bb:=(xx < xxur) ? 1: (xx > wwur) ? 2 : (xx > 50 ) ? 0 :  bb[1]
    bb

ttrr = FFF(rsrs,35,65)
rrmin = 0.0
rrmin :=(ttrr==2) ? 100 : (rsrs[0]<rrmin[0] ? rsrs[0] : rrmin[1])
rrii = rsrs[0]>rrmin[0] ? 1 : 0

bgcolor(lime, transp=50)
```

Comment: when I add this

rrmin  = 0.0
and then
rrmin :=(ttrr==2) ? 100 : (rsrs[0]<rrmin[0] ? rsrs[0] : rrmin[1])

then an error notification:
Error at 444:0 Variable `rrmin` is already declared.

Comment: As @G.Lebret said: Edit your question and paste the full code. it is hard to help you without the context

Comment: Edit my answer with the code [you posted on Telegram](https://t.me/PineCodersQA/54492)